# Query Error: Error: ER_NON_UNIQ_ERROR: Column 'candidate_id' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, php

This is my query

```
SELECT user_name,candidate_id
FROM user AS usr INNER JOIN candidate as can
ON usr.user_id = can.entered_by
INNER JOIN candidate_joborder as canjo
ON can.candidate_id = canjo.candidate_id
WHERE usr.user_id = 1
```

And my fiddle

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gWr5g2222yAE8Fh1Gc6Awf/2

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is right, only

```
    SELECT user_name, can.candidate_id
FROM user AS usr INNER JOIN candidate as can
ON usr.user_id = can.entered_by
INNER JOIN candidate_joborder as canjo
ON can.candidate_id = canjo.candidate_id
WHERE usr.user_id = 1
```

Comment: Yeah i missed this. can.candidate_id